# How to refer to a piped object inside ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying this code:

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length*100) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Sepal.Length))+
    geom_col()+
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", high = "green", mid = "red", midpoint = median(.$Sepal.Length))
```

The focus of this question is on the `midpoint` part. When I run this, I get the error:

```
Error in median(.$Sepal.Length) : object '.' not found
```

I also tried:

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length*100) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Sepal.Length))+
    geom_col()+
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", high = "green", mid = "red", midpoint = median(Sepal.Length))
```

And I got a similar error:

```
Error in median(Sepal.Length) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

What is the proper way to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Maybe this could do the trick   `...midpoint = median(iris$Sepal.Length*100))`.

Comment: That works, but I'm guessing they need to refrain from calling data again for some reason. Is there something preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Yes, this is not an option for me - this was just example data and I actually have 10+ lines of piping. I need to explicitly refer to the piped object, as in question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via the trick below, but this is ugly and unelegant, amongst other potential side effects. Use with caution!

Practically, you 'hard-assign' a variable inside the pipe:
here the code:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length*100) %>% 
  {. ->> tmp} %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", high = "green", mid = "red", 
                       midpoint = median(tmp$Sepal.Length))

rm(tmp) # remove temporary object
```

**Edit** : following @jd-caddell I slightly adapted my code to perfectly matched your use case.

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool, didn't know you could do that. However, I don't think it is working as desired. The middle should be red with the outside green and yellow.

Comment: If you want to rearrange your pipe (push the tmp to after the mutate), I'll delete my answer so you can have it.

Comment: As noted above, I'd be careful with this answer. It does seem to create and store the tmp object. If you are iterating through many of these, or the data is large, you need to consider this.

Comment: This is very interesting! I never encountered the double-headed arrow operator until now.

Comment: Like I said, I am though not very comfortable with this option, and I would love if a real R specialist would give his opinion.